# PrintPreviewDialog prints blank pages

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, print-preview

I see many reports of this and I have tried a few things that are suggested but none work in my case. I think in my case I do not understand how the PrintPreviewDialog works so I am not connecting the document with the print button correctly.

I create a document in a richtextbox that is many A4 print pages long. I then use the following from a button in the Winform. The second function is event where the pages are made. (Some of the code below comes from others so thanks to them)

```
        private void btn_SaveBitmap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
            PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            printPreviewDialog1.Icon = new Icon("..\\..\\braille.ico");
            

            printDocument1.PrintPage += PrintDocument_PrintPage;
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();  
           
        }


        private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //comes in here for every page it needs to make

            int charactersOnPage = 0;
            int linesPerPage = 0;
            Font drawFont = new Font(rchtxtbx_braille.Font.ToString(), rchtxtbx_braille.Font.Size);

            // Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters
            // of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
            e.Graphics.MeasureString(rchtxtbx_braille.Text, drawFont,
                e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
                out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

            // Draws the string within the bounds of the page
            e.Graphics.DrawString(rchtxtbx_braille.Text, drawFont, Brushes.Black,
                e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

            // Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
            rchtxtbx_braille.Text = rchtxtbx_braille.Text.Substring(charactersOnPage);

            // Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
            e.HasMorePages = (rchtxtbx_braille.Text.Length > 0);   

        }
```

This all looks good in the preview dialog and I can see I have many pages and they all look correct. In the preview in top left I press the print icon and then I see although the laptop has access to 7 printers all I get here is PDF printer. If I click to run and I get a page printed but it is blank.

So two issues

1. Why do I not see all 7 printers in the preview dialog?
2. How do you make the dialog print the actual page rather than ignore it a print blank?

Any ideas please on how to make it print the correct pages. Thanks.

Comment: _If I click to run and I get a page printed but it is blank..._ Because `rchtxtbx_braille.Text = rchtxtbx_braille.Text.Substring(charactersOnPage);`. You are clearing the `RTB.Text` and when you print from the preview dialog, there's nothing to print. Use a `StringBuilder` to append the `RTB.Text` in the button click event and use it in the `PrintPage` event where ever you see `rchtxtbx_braille.Text` in your code. Also, `printDocument1` and `printPreviewDialog1` are disposable object. You should dispose of them afterward. Right after `printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();`.

Answer (score 0):

After much head scratching it dawned on me that can work it just needs to put the text back into the richtextbox. I thought once it made the preview that it printed the preview. Apparently not the preview only gives it the figures for the print and not the image to print. It gets the print image from the original source. So now at the end when the Richtextbox is empty I say there are no more pages and then replace the text. It is now working.

```
 private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //needed to replace text into richtextbox after preview
        
        private void btn_SaveBitmap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
            PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            printPreviewDialog1.Icon = new Icon("..\\..\\braille.ico");

            sb.Append(rchtxtbx_braille.Text);

            printDocument1.PrintPage += PrintDocument_PrintPage;
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
            
            printDocument1.Dispose();
            printPreviewDialog1.Dispose();
        }


        private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //comes in here for every page it needs to make

            int charactersOnPage = 0;
            int linesPerPage = 0;
            Font drawFont = new Font(rchtxtbx_braille.Font.ToString(), rchtxtbx_braille.Font.Size);

            // Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters
            // of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
            e.Graphics.MeasureString(rchtxtbx_braille.Text, drawFont,
                e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
                out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

            // Draws the string within the bounds of the page
            e.Graphics.DrawString(rchtxtbx_braille.Text, drawFont, Brushes.Black,
                e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);


            // Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
             rchtxtbx_braille.Text = rchtxtbx_braille.Text.Substring(charactersOnPage);
           

            // Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
            // replace the text when the window is empty so we have something to print
            // otherwise we print a blank document.
            
             if (rchtxtbx_braille.Text.Length > 0)
             {
                 e.HasMorePages = true;
             }
             else
             {
                 e.HasMorePages = false; //say no more pages
                 rchtxtbx_braille.Text = sb.ToString(); //replace text
             }
        }
```